# Trouble with Backbone.js fetching JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery, backbone.js

I'm working through some tutorial code and like most tutorial code, the "json" object is faked by adding it as a simple object within the the javascript file. I'm trying instead to fetch the JSON from a file I've got hosted on a server. I'm trying to make this a bit more realistic.  Nonetheless, I can't seem to get the binding to work.

My demo code (which I've got working), but with the "json" object inside the javascript can be seen here.

[jsfiddle that works](http://jsfiddle.net/rsturim/veD3C/)

My desired work can be seen here.

[jsfiddle that doesn't](http://jsfiddle.net/rsturim/sfzun/)

My remote json is located here [json file](http://sturim.me/contacts.json)-- if you "fork" my 2 fiddles, the test harness is there for your testing (backbone, underscore, jquery all onboard).

I believe the crux of my problems surrounds the "Collection" and the "View" that uses the collection.

```
var Contacts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Contact,
    url: 'http://sturim.me/contacts.json',
    parse: function(data) {
        return data.objects;
    }            
});

//define master view
var ContactsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#contacts"),

    initialize: function() {
        this.collection = new Contacts();
        this.collection.fetch();
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.find("article").remove();
        _.each(this.collection.models, function(item) {
            this.renderContact(item);
        }, this);
    },

    renderContact: function(item) {
        var contactView = new ContactView({
            model: item
        });
        this.$el.append(contactView.render().el);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, The second jsfiddle doesn't work because of browser security restructions. You cannot query your personal domain from inside of a jsfiddle.

Second, in your `Contacts` `parse` function, `data` is a string containing the contents of the file, so it is up to you to turn that response into an object.

```
parse: function(data) {
    return JSON.parse(data).objects;
}
```

Lastly, `fetch` is an asynchronous request, so your logic will attempt to render before the request has finished. You should be rendering based on events triggered on the view.

```
initialize: function() {
    this.collection = new Contacts();

    // When the contents of the collection are set, render the view.
    this.collection.on('reset', function(){
        this.render();
    }, this);

    this.collection.fetch();
},
```

Comment: thanks @loganfsmyth -- that's got me much closer. I wasn't able to make the parse function work exactly how you had it. I had to do this: "return response.contactsHolder". Which did get things to work better. Also, is the 'reset' an appropriate place to register events?  Does fetch trigger 'reset'?

Comment: @rsturim Glad it's working. I don't know how `response.contactsHolder` would work given the code you posted has no variable named response, and the JSON you posted uses `contacts`, so I assume you must have changed it. 'reset' is fired after a fetch because fetch deletes and recreates the contents of the collection, so it is a reasonable place to put that rendering. Backbone is very flexible though, so it is more up to your preference on where to put that.

Comment: thanks for your help -- that clarifies things for me quite a bit.